# POJO to MultiValueMap mapping/binding/conversion in spring 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a POJO I need to format as a MultiValueMap.  This MultiValueMap will be used as the request in a POST method using the restTemplate class and will be passed along to my web service as contentType application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Are there any tools or utilities that will do the POJO -> MultiValueMap conversion for me?

sample pojo:

```
public class SampleDto implements Serializable, Idable, Comparable<SampleDto> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer id;

    private Boolean active;

    private String lastName;

    private List<SurgeonClinicDto> surgeonClinics = new ArrayList<SurgeonClinicDto>();
    private List<PromptValueDto> promptValues = new ArrayList<PromptValueDto>();

    private Date lastUpdated = new Date();

    public SampleDto() {

    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Boolean getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(Boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Date getLastUpdated() {
        return lastUpdated;
    }

    public void setLastUpdated(Date lastUpdated) {
        this.lastUpdated = lastUpdated;
    }

    public List<SurgeonClinicDto> getSurgeonClinics() {
        return surgeonClinics;
    }

    public void setSurgeonClinics(List<SurgeonClinicDto> surgeonClinics) {
        this.surgeonClinics = surgeonClinics;
    }

    public List<PromptValueDto> getPromptValues() {
        return promptValues;
    }

    public void setPromptValues(List<PromptValueDto> promptValues) {
        this.promptValues = promptValues;
    }

    public int compareTo(SampleDto o) {

        if (getLastName() != null && o.getLastName() != null
                && getLastName().compareTo(o.getLastName()) != 0) {
            return getLastName().compareTo(o.getLastName());
        }
        if (getActive() != null && o.getActive() != null
                && getActive().compareTo(o.getActive()) != 0) {
            return getActive().compareTo(o.getActive());
        }
        if (getLastUpdated() != null && o.getLastUpdated() != null
                && getLastUpdated().compareTo(o.getLastUpdated()) != 0) {
            return getLastUpdated().compareTo(o.getLastUpdated());
        }
        if (getId() != null && o.getId() != null
                && getId().compareTo(o.getId()) != 0) {
            return getId().compareTo(o.getId());
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

After MultiValueMap is converted to contentType: application/x-www-form-urlencoded by calling POST on restTemplate object:

```
id=11752&active=true&lastName=Brownie&
promptValues[0].id=12&promptValues[0].miscPromptId=882&promptValues[0].value=meFirst&
promptValues[1].id=13&promptValues[1].miscPromptId=881&promptValues[1].value=youToo&
surgeonClinics[0].address1=newAddress&surgeonClinics[0].address2=newAddress2&surgeonClinics[0].city=clinic City&
surgeonClinics[0].email=email@clinic1.com&surgeonClinics[0].fax=123.456.7890&surgeonClinics[0].id=33273&
surgeonClinics[0].name=clinic name&surgeonClinics[0].phone=890-098-4567&
surgeonClinics[0].zip=34567&surgeonClinics[0].surgeryCenter1=MySurgeryCenter1&
surgeonClinics[0].surgeryCenter2=MySurgeryCenter2&
surgeonClinics[1].address1=newAddress11&surgeonClinics[1].address2=newAddress22&surgeonClinics[1].city=clinic2 City&
surgeonClinics[1].email=email@clinic2.com&surgeonClinics[1].fax=123.456.7890&surgeonClinics[1].id=33274&
surgeonClinics[1].name=clinic2 name&surgeonClinics[1].phone=890-098-4567&
surgeonClinics[1].zip=34567&
surgeonClinics[1].surgeryCenter1=MySurgeryCenter21&surgeonClinics[1].surgeryCenter2=MySurgeryCenter22
```

Comment: show the pojo and the map you expect.

Comment: added some code samples to demonstrate the question.

Comment: You already asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928163/spring-resttemplate-post-parameters-from-complex-object

Comment: yes, and sometimes asking different questions or approaching problems in a different way lead to a solution.

Answer (score 11):

You can use Jackson objectMapper:

```
MultiValueMap valueMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
Map<String, Object> fieldMap = objectMapper.convertValue(requestObject, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});
valueMap.setAll(fieldMap);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with reflection and/or introspection (I never remember the correct name).  This is a variation of Serialization, so you might want to look in the Serialization implementation.

Another option is to create an interface similar to this

```
putlic interface ToMap
{
  Map<String, String> toMap();
}
```

And implement it on the classes in question.

For your pojo it might look like this:

```
Map<String, String> toMap()
{
    int index;
    StringBuilder key = new StringBuidler();
    Map<String, String> returnValue = new HashMap<String, String>();

    returnValue.put("id", id);
    returnValue.put("active", active);
    returnValue.put("lastName", lastName);

    index = 0;
    for (SurgeonClinicDto surgeonClinic : surgeonClinics)
    {
        key.setLength(0);
        key.append("surgeonClinic[");
        key.append(index);
        key.append("].field1");

        returnValue.put(key.toString(), surgeonClinic[index].field1);

        key.setLength(0);
        key.append("surgeonClinic[");
        key.append(index);
        key.append("].field2");

        returnValue.put(key.toString(), surgeonClinic[index].field2);

        ... more stuff here...

    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to send it in the format that you have specified in your question then you may want to do something like what [DwB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3987718/1367563) suggested, however I think you may find it easier to convert if you use a more object orientated approach such as [JSON](http://www.json.org/), there are lots of libraries to convert between POJO->JSON. Another advantage is that JSON handles stores numbers/string/booleans separately therefore it is easier to convert back to a POJO whereas if you send the data as in your example you will need to convert all the String objects back into what type they are e.g. id will need to be converted String->int and active converted String->boolean.

So in JSON it may look something like this:

```
dto = {
    id : 11752,
    active : true,
    lastName : "Brownie",
    promptValues : [
        {id : 12, miscPromptId : 882, value : "meFirst"},
        {id : 13, miscPromptId : 881, value : "youToo"}
    ],
    surgeonClinics = [{..etc..}]
}
```

Obviously you could do something similar with XML, but I like this simple solution when I want to send data simply and all in one line. The JSON libraries are getting better and some can pretty much generate this from your object by reflection.

Anyway just a suggestion.